# list new wordlist in which words match given prefix (python comprehension question)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, prefix

I need some help to make the following question in python.
1.function called starts_with(prefix, wordlist) that takes as inputs a string prefix and a list of strings wordlist, and that uses a list comprehension to return a list consisting of all words from wordlist that begin with prefix.

What I did is

```
def starts_with (prefix, wordlist):
    if prefix == wordlist[0][:len(prefix)]:
    return [wordlist[0]]+ starts_with(prefix,wordlist[1:])
```

I just found out it is neither an error and comprehension. I have no idea how should I make this in comprehension.

Comment: could you please explain "neither an error and comprehension"?

Answer (score 1):

```
def starts_with(prefix, wordlist):
        wordswithPrefixList =[]
        for word in wordlist:
            if word.startswith(prefix):
                wordswithPrefixList.append(word)

        return wordswithPrefixList
print(starts_with("test", ["test2","test1","sfsdf"]))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation too along with the code which will help to make your answer comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
def starts_with(prefix, wordlist):
    return [word for word in wordlist if word.startswith(prefix)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `filter`:

```
def starts_with(prefix, wordlist):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(prefix),wordlist))
```